# Emacs Lisp: Can't set any value to variable named 's'

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

This is rather queer. I can't set any value to a variable if it is named 's' in an interactive session:

```
(setq s 'foo)
=> foo

s
=> nil
```

Why?

### Update 1:

Here is the output from describe-variable on s:

```
s is void as a variable.

Documentation:
Not documented as a variable.
```

Why is it that s is kept void in emacs lisp as a global variable?

### Update 2:

Turned out, it doesn't happen on a vanilla emacs (meaning one of the modules I load in .emacs or some code in .emacs is causing this).
So the question now is:

**What would the original source look like when describe-variable yields "`<var>` is void as a variable"?**

I tried it with `setq`, `defconst`, `defvar`, and `defcustom`, but none of those produced the message I'm showing.

### Update 3:

The message shown above is produced when the variable is literally not bound (though it can be `fbound`).

```
(describe-variable 'non-existent)
=> "non-existent is void as a variable.

Documentation:
Not documented as a variable."
```

So latest question is: **Is there any way to prevent a certain variable name 
from being bound?**

Comment: Does this occur if you start Emacs with `emacs -q`? What is your version of Emacs? What does `(symbol-plist 's)` evaluate to?

Comment: What version of emacs is this, and what modules do you have loaded? I can't reproduce this with GNU Emacs 23.1 on my machine.

Comment: @Gilles and @Ray: Hmm. I thought this would happen with `emacs -q` but no. s can be set with a vanilla emacs. FWIW: GNU Emacs 24.0.50.1 (i686-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 2.18.3) of 2010-10-01

Comment: I suppose it is one of the modules I load in .emacs.el. **Anybody experiencing the same issue?**

Comment: I can't reproduce this with GNU Emacs 23.2.1.

Comment: emacs 23.1.1 and xemacs 21.5 both let me set s

Comment: Bigger question, *why* do you want to prevent a variable from being bound?  And I believe the answer is "no" unless you change the interpreter.

Comment: Could you post your .emacs file (and any other elisp files relevant) somewhere online?

Answer (score 1):

An answer to your revised question:

```
(defvar s)
```

The only thing is that this won't let you use `describe-variable` on it interactively.

(You could then do something like `(setplist 's '(variable-documentation "Meh"))` to set a description for it without going through `defvar`.

Comment: Is it really? `(defvar qq)` => qq. `(setq qq 'foo)` => foo. `qq` => foo

Answer (score 1):

Just bisect your init file (`~/.emacs`) recursively until you find the sexp that causes the problem. If it is a sexp that loads another library then either don't use that library or fix it by first finding out what its problem is, the same way: bisect the code in that library recursively, etc.

This is a binary search, and it is very quick.  You can quickly comment out half, then 3/4, 7/8, etc. of your file, using `M-x comment-region` (I bind it to `C-x ;`).  with a prefix arg, `comment-region` uncomments.

Answer (score 0):

With Emacs 23.1, running the following code makes `C-h v s RET` show “s is void as a variable.”, but I can't reproduce the inconsistency between `setq` and retrieving the value of the variable (which I agree is weird).

```
(setq s t)
(make-local-variable 's)
(makunbound 's)
```

I suspect an Emacs 24-specific feature or bug.